# C# method generic return type casting

Tags: c#, generics

I am trying to create a method in an interface with a generic return type but I fail to cast the generic to a specific type/class. But if I put the generic on the interface instead of the method I am able to do the casting.

In other words, why does this work

```
public class Rain {
    public string propA {get;set;}
}
public interface IFoo<T> {
    T foo();
}

public class Bar : IFoo<Rain> {
    Rain foo() { 
        //...
        return new Rain();
    }
}

public bar = new Bar();
Rain rain = bar.foo();
```

But it is not possible to do this?

```
public class Rain {
    public string propA {get;set;}
}
public interface IFoo {
    T foo<T>();
}

public class Bar : IFoo {
    T foo<T>() { 
        //...
        return new Rain();
    }
}

public bar = new Bar();
Rain rain = bar.foo<Rain>();
```

Is there any other way around ( without using `Convert.ChangeType()`)?

Comment: In your second version, you are declaring that Foo returns something of type T - type can be ANYTHING. but at the point of calling Foo and you pass the type T, it must return something of type T, yet you always return Rain. Its essentially the same as saying you are going to return a string but returning an int, of course it wont compile

Comment: To help sharpen your misunderstanding, visualise what you expect the compiler to do if your second code sample was instead `public bar = new Bar();
Bobby rain = bar.foo<Bobby>();`. Now, the only reasonable thing for the compiler to do is say 'no I can't do that'. Thus, it must **always** say that - regardless of whether you replace `Bobby` with `Rain`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is:

```
// On this line you specify that the interface's generic type paramter 'T' is of type 'Rain',
// so the method implements the interface and returns a 'Rain'
public class Bar : IFoo<Rain> {
    Rain foo() { // <= implements IFoo<Rain>.foo, where T = Rain so foo returns 'Rain'
        return new Rain();

// In this version, the generic type parameter is declared on the method. It could be any type when the method is called, yet you always return a 'Rain'
public class Bar : IFoo {
    T foo<T>() { // <= implements IFoo.foo<T> but the type of T is not specified yet
        return new Rain();
```

The "solution" for this depends on what your intentions are.

- **Why would you *not* want the generic parameter on the interface?**
- **Also, why would you want a generic parameter on the `foo` method, if you always return `Rain` anyways?**

Of course, in any case, you could just cast it like this:

```
T Foo<T>()
{
    object result;
    result = new Rain();
    return (T)result; // note, this will throw at runtime if 'result' cannot be cast to 'T'
}

// call like this:
Bar.Foo<Rain>();
```

But I think your first approach `IFoo<T>` makes perfect sense so why not use it?

**UPDATE**

Based on your comment: You can also define multiple generic parameters:

```
public interface IFoo<T1, T2>
{
    T1 foo();
    T2 foo2();
}

// implementation:
public class Bar : IFoo<Rain, Other>
{
    Rain foo() { /* ... */ }
    Other foo2() { /* ... */ }
}
```

Comment: Since `Rain` is a class (and therefor not a value type) there's no boxing involved. [`Boxing`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/boxing-and-unboxing) is the casting of a value type to a reference type. Also, if `Rain` was a value type, this would throw an `InvalidCastException` - you can only unbox to the exact same type that is boxed, even if there's an implicit conversion from the type that is boxed to the type you want to unbox. Other then that, this is a good answer.

Comment: So in fact, you can just do `return new Rain() as T` (that would return `default(T)` if `Rain` can't be cast to `T`)

Comment: @ZoharPeled Valid point. `T` **could** be a value type though. Also, I wouldn't use `as` in this case, I prefer code to throw on unexpected behavior (like when you messed up this design and the cast is not possible) than just silently return null.

Comment: @marsze I dont want the generic parameter on the interface because I have more than one generic method with different T types. Also I want to let the various implementations of that interface to decide what the return type is

Comment: @DevelopeCruz You can also define multiple parameters `IFoo<T1, T2>` .. see the update in my answer. I think that's probably what you need in your case and would be the most "correct" and practical way to do it.

Comment: @DevelopeCruz "Also I want to let the various implementations of that interface to decide what the return type is " - in which case the interface is of very limited, respectively no use whatsoever. If your interface doesn't restrict what the implementations can return, just get rid of the interface. Or better yet, rethink your design.

Answer (score 10):

The second code snippet is impossible to compile because `Rain` is not `T`.

When the type parameter is supplied in the class, there's no problem because the method can only return the type that was already supplied in the class declaration. In other words - `T foo()` becomes `Rain foo`.

However, when the type parameter is supplied to the method, then the method is obligated to return whatever type is supplied to it - so you can't return anything other than `T`. In other words, the compiler can't enforce the calling method to only use `foo<Rain>()`, but it can enforce the `foo` method to return `T`.

Answer (score 0):

If you need your interface to support an arbitrary set of classes, and what classes are used is determined by the caller then something like this is the most general solution.

```
public class Bar : IFoo {
    T foo<T>() { 
        if (typeof(T)==typeof(Rain))
           return new Rain() as T;
        if (typeof(T)==typeof(Snow))
           return new Snow() as T;
        Throw new ArgumentException("Not implemented for " + typeof(T).Name);
    }
}
```

If all your T's have a common interface and that is what you are interested in you could do;

```
public class Snow : IWeather {...}
public class Rain: IWeather {...}
public class Bar : IFoo {
    IWeather  foo<T>() T : IWeather { 
        if (typeof(T)==typeof(Rain))
           return new Rain();
        if (typeof(T)==typeof(Snow))
           return new Snow();
        Throw new ArgumentException("Not implemented for " + typeof(T).Name);
    }
}
```